# The answer lies within this question!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> I lie inside this question, and I hide behind a mask.
>   I don't think you'll see me from my appearance.
>   I hope you conclude where I'm too,
>   but I doubt you will without clever thinking.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is

> "Hello, I'm the answer, just waiting for you :D"

It's hidden with

> < ? tag. Click edit to see it

Answer (score 36):

The answer is quite simply this.

Comment: Nope! Nice try though, but there'd be quotes around "this question"

Comment: @warspyking, no, seriously, look more closely at this answer. See past its appearance. Use your clever thinking. ;)

Comment: Clever, but no.

Comment: Even once you've spotted the thing?

Comment: What thing? I'm confused now lol!

Comment: The ***thing***! The thing in my answer that is like the thing in the question! The thing that you can see in my answer in the same way that you can see it in the question! That thing! :)

Comment: Oh now I see it IN your answer too. Lol...

Comment: Exactly! I think I got it first!

Comment: I accepted the outright one lol.

Comment: aw! mine has comedy value! can't you swap?

Comment: Lol no... The accepted has an actual description and actually gives the answer properly

Comment: awwwwww! wit counts for nothing around here. Mine gives the answer *with style*. ;)

Comment: Actually I like this answer better :)

Comment: @oerkelens yay! go, this answer! better *and* earlier! :)

Comment: @A E The answer should give future visitors the answer outright and not hide it, albeit the question his a crucial detail in itself only available to clever minds. I did just upvote though :P

Comment: Actually A E, add a description and I suppose I could accept...

Comment: Thanks @warspyking but don't worry about it, I'm not really bothered. ;)